# Jhipster relationship added at the end

Tags: user-interface, jhipster, auto-generate

Hi when jhipster auto generates UI for the entity it currently puts all relationships at the end. Is there any way we can define where to put the generated relationship. Fields are generated in the order they are defined in the json file so let say I want to add the generated relationship somewhere in between those two fields. Is such thing possible without modifying the UI manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's currently not supported because fields and relationships are stored in 2 different lists per entity. Changing this would require significant work as it impacts many places in the generator.

Comment: Thanks for the info I will deal with the manual work for now.